# How to Scroll with in a class in selenium in java

Tags: java, scroll, selenium-webdriver, automation

So , I have this scroll bar with in a class. It is browser default . I have tried scrolling through click & hold , window.scrollBy, sending Keys.Down etc . But nothing works . 
!This is where I want to scroll. I have clicked on the downloads and then tried to send Keys.Down . But it doesnot work . [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muyfx.png)

I am out of ideas . Help is appreciated .

Comment: have you tried using `JavascriptExecutor` Interface?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say JavascriptExecutor would be your best bet too.

Here's a simple example of how I handle scrolling to where I need to be:

```
//element you're wanting to scroll to
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("example");

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//get location of element to scroll to
int x = e.getLocation.getX();
int y = e.getLocation.getY();

//use js to scroll to element
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + x + "," + y + ");");
```

If doesn't work then there are multiple other JavaScript functions you can use to manipulate the browser into scrolling where you need to.

It's also worth bearing in mind the effect things like static headers or headers that change size on scrolling can have on the final location of you element.